# How do I integrate FileHelper 3.15 into my project. I'm currently getting errors

Tags: vb.net

I just installed FileHelper version 3.15 and I'm having issues. I used some code from their examples.

```
Dim lDetectedFormat As FileHelpers.Detection.RecordFormatInfo = formats(0)

    Dim lDetectedClass As Type = lDetectedFormat.ClassBuilderAsDelimited.CreateRecordClass()

    Dim lFieldInfoList As New List(Of FieldInfo)(lDetectedFormat.ClassBuilderAsDelimited.FieldCount)
    For Each lField As FileHelpers.Dynamic.DelimitedFieldBuilder In lDetectedFormat.ClassBuilderAsDelimited.Fields
        lFieldInfoList.Add(lDetectedClass.GetField(lField.FieldName))
    Next

    Dim lFileEngine As New FileHelperAsyncEngine(lDetectedClass)
    Dim lRecNo As Integer = 0
    lFileEngine.BeginReadFile(cReadingsFile)
    Try
        While True
            Dim lRec As Object = lFileEngine.ReadNext()
            If lRec Is Nothing Then
                Exit While
            End If

            Trace.WriteLine("Record " + lRecNo)
            lFieldInfoList.ForEach(Function(f) Trace.WriteLine("   " + f.Name + " = " + f.GetValue(lRec)))

            lRecNo += 1
        End While
    Finally
        lFileEngine.Close()
    End Try
```

I'm getting errors on the following: formats(0),  FieldInfo and FileHelperAsyncEngine.

I'm pretty dumb about the FileHelper engine and I need a little help to get started. What I'm trying to do is read a CVS file that has multiple delimiters, quotes and comma.

One more thing: I used Nuget package manager to get FileHelper. Also, if there's a better way to do it in regular code, I'm open to that. Thanks for looking.

Comment: `I'm getting errors...` are those errors a secret? Can you share?

Comment: @plutonix Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm getting errors from the above code. The errors in the compiler are the words: "formats", "Fieldinfo", and "FileHelperAsyncEngine". thanks...

Comment: @Plutonix  upgrade to previous comment: The errors the compiler are giving are either "variable is not defined"... "is not declared". Maybe that's more of what you wanted.

Comment: for the last 2 it sounds like you did not import the library so VS doesnt know what a `FileHelperAsyncEngine` is.  from the code shown, there is no declaration for `formats(0)` which is what the error says

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I added a reference to their dll in the "packages" folder. Can you think of anything else I could do? Maybe I need another "imports" statement? (going to check that)

Comment: adding a reference (which should have happened when you added the package) is different than telling the compiler which parts of you app are using it.  Thats done with an `Imports` statement at the top, probably `Imports FileHelper` you could use Object Browser to find out the name

Comment: I just used the import statement: Imports FileHelpers, but it didn't make any difference when I tried to compile agan. Also, this site has given a warning for "extended discussions". Maybe we should stop?

Comment: The package could have multiple types and namespaces, `Imports FileHelper` was a guess and is why I suggested you use Object Browser to find out.

Comment: You had the import statement right. It just needed a "s" to go on the end. I used the object browser and found a lot of things to look at... need to take some time to digest them...